# Which preposition to use here?"Of" or "among"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across a blank in a sentence which was:

The peacock is perhaps the most beautiful _____ male birds.

What should I fill there? Of or among?

Comment: Updated the answer, sorry for misleading you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be *among*.

> The peacock is perhaps the most beautiful *among* male birds.

After some research, I came to the conclusion that *of* is also acceptable here.

> The peacock is perhaps the most beautiful *of* male birds.

When it comes down to comparing related things, *of* is a perfectly valid option.

> The blue whale is the largest of all the animals.
>
> He's the best looking of the three brothers.
>
> The Eiffel Tower is the most famous of all Paris's landmarks.